# Best way to write this code, want to reduce the no of if else

Tags: kotlin, if-statement

Some times I don't like no of nested if else in kotlin. Is there any way to write better code? Am giving one example, you can choose any other example. Please share your feedback.

```
  suspend fun setStoreImages(call: ApplicationCall) {
    val storeImagesMapper = call.receive<ArrayList<StoreImageMapper>>()
    val employeeEmail = getEmailFromJWT(call)
    if (employeeEmail == null){
      call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "No employee email id passed")
    }else {
      val errorStr = StoreApis.createStoreImages(storeImagesMapper, employeeEmail)
      if (errorStr == null) {
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Created)
      } else {
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errorStr)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A when statement is nice for reducing multiple if-else. In this case you can get the `errorStr` early if `employeeEmail` is available by using `?.let`.

```
suspend fun setStoreImages(call: ApplicationCall) {
    val storeImagesMapper = call.receive<ArrayList<StoreImageMapper>>()
    val employeeEmail = getEmailFromJWT(call)
    val errorStr = employeeEmail?.let { StoreApis.createStoreImages(storeImagesMapper, it) }
    when {
        employeeEmail == null -> call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "No employee email id passed")
        errorStr == null -> call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Created)
        else -> call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errorStr)
    }
}
```

An alternate strategy is to do early returns instead of doing else statements.

```
suspend fun setStoreImages(call: ApplicationCall) {
    val storeImagesMapper = call.receive<ArrayList<StoreImageMapper>>()
    val employeeEmail = getEmailFromJWT(call)
    if (employeeEmail == null) {
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "No employee email id passed")
        return
    }
    val errorStr = StoreApis.createStoreImages(storeImagesMapper, employeeEmail)
    if (errorStr == null) {
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Created)
        return
    }
    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errorStr)
}
```

Comment: The first way you suggested is better as early return flow is not good to read

Comment: I agree `when` is better in this case. There is only one intermediate value calcuated (`errorStr`). But sometimes you have multiple intermediate calculations, so the first approach would get messy.

Comment: Yes it would get messy, in that case better is to mix both I guess

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple way to do this.

Lets take your example. We can use return key to skip the else condition like this. Now the code if it goes into the if condition then it will return without executing the remaining lines of code.

```
suspend fun setStoreImages(call: ApplicationCall) {
    val storeImagesMapper = call.receive<ArrayList<StoreImageMapper>>()
    val employeeEmail = getEmailFromJWT(call)
    if (employeeEmail == null){
      call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "No employee email id passed")
      return
    }
      val errorStr = StoreApis.createStoreImages(storeImagesMapper, employeeEmail)
      if (errorStr == null) {
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Created)
      } else {
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errorStr)
      }
    }
```

We could take one more step to remove the remaining if else using when. This is useful especially when one variable might take multiple values. Something like the switch statement but more elegant.

```
suspend fun setStoreImages(call: ApplicationCall) {
    val storeImagesMapper = call.receive<ArrayList<StoreImageMapper>>()
    val employeeEmail = getEmailFromJWT(call)
    if (employeeEmail == null){
      call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "No employee email id passed")
      return
    }
      val errorStr = StoreApis.createStoreImages(storeImagesMapper, employeeEmail)
      when(errorStr) {
        null->all.respond(HttpStatusCode.Created)
        else-> call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errorStr)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the tip

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the code using extensions function
And `When
Eg

```
suspend fun ApplicationCall.setStoreImages() {
    val storeImagesMapper = receive<ArrayList<StoreImageMapper>>()
    val employeeEmail = getEmailFromJWT(this)
    when (employeeEmail){
      null  -> respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "No employee email id passed")
    else -> {
StoreApis.createStoreImages(storeImagesMapper, employeeEmail).let {
      when (it) {
       null -> respond(HttpStatusCode.Created)
      else -> espond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, it!!)
      }
    } 
  }
}
  }
```